# Web Server for Android Firmware OTA Update

Tags: android, webserver, ota

I'm currently want to develop Android Firmware OTA Update for our product.
While I'm research how to do that I learned that I will need web server for the firmware.
Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Can anyone help me what is the most suitable web server I should use?
Really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: there is nothing different from regular file download from any kind of server. OTA update is a file. So you basically need to download a file, not an `OTA update`

Answer (score 0):

As OTA update is  very sensitive process for customer perceptive, You has to use good server.

Please check [ESP8266 OTA Updates with Arduino IDE](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-ota-updates-with-arduino-ide-over-the-air/)